# Regex on /^Subject and /^From at the same time

Tags: regex

Where is the mistake in this regex and how do I possibly match two conditions at the same time for both subject field and from field? The subject is "empty line" (there is nothing written in the subject field) and the email comes from "assistant@mail.com" then accept mail:

```
/^From:(.*)assistant\@gmail\.com|^Subject:\s*$/ OK
```

Would be really thankful for any help at all.

Comment: What do you get? How do you run the regex?

Comment: Can you separate the text you want to match from the regex?

Comment: I think the issue is the `$` sign, as it fails to match expressions that are one-line long

Comment: Can you add an extract of the email headers? A solution would be to use multi-line matching, but to produce such an answer one would need to know the order in which the two Subject and From lines appear in the matched text and whether there is any other data inbetween

Comment: Current answers are missing the fact that OP wants *both* a specific From and a specific Subject, using alternation (`|`) won't cut it as it will match *either* of those, not only when they are both present.

Comment: That's right, Aaron. It has to match both conditions at the same time, therefore all the suggestions here will not work. If the condition 1 AND the condition 2 are true = accept it. If either the condition 1 or the condition 2 are not true = do not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple lines, one option could be to first match the `From` part and then match 0+ lines in between and then match the `Subject` part.

If it is the otherway around, you could turn the logic around imthe pattern.

```
^From:.*?assistant@gmail\.com.*(?:\n.*)*\nSubject:\s*$
```

That will match:

- `^From:.*?` Match `From:` from the start of the string followed by any char non greedy
- `assistant@gmail\.com` Match email
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:\n.*)` Match 0+ times a newline and the whole line until the end of the line
- `\nSubject:\s*$` Match a newline, Subject, 0+ times a whitespace char and assert the end of the line

[Regen demo](https://regex101.com/r/knKSi5/1)

The other way around:

```
^Subject:\s*(?:\n.*)*\nFrom:.*?assistant@gmail\.com
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/knKSi5/2)

Comment: Thank you. That's a good one too as well. However, "From" line normally comes before the "Subject", is that not right?

Comment: @Dennis You are welcome. I could not determine the order from the question so I provided both options how you might do it.

Answer (score 0):

I made an assumption about your text and how it is laid out.

Does this work?

`/(From:\sassistant@gmail\.com)|(Subject:.*)$/`

I capture the email in one group or match the empty subject in another group, assuming the text you're matching is one line long.

See here for the match: https://regex101.com/r/CP0jfc/2/

Comment: Thank you. It's also fine without any parenthesis. I made a mistake using them as well like this (.*)

Comment: @Dennis, if this helped you, please mark the answered as accepted by clicking on the tick mark ✓ on top-left of an answer

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was all wrong. It doesn't work. It matches either of these two, but it has to match them together. If the condition 1 AND the condition 2 are true = accept it. If either the condition 1 or the condition 2 are not true = do not accept it.

Comment: You wouldn't add logic to the regex. Whatever programming language you're using would extract both capture group values and test against those

Answer (score 0):

May be you get some idea from this.

```
^From:\s*assistant\@gmail\.com|^Subject:\s*$
```

Demo:: https://regex101.com/r/zDzbyX/1

Comment: Thank you. This one worked. I had a little error in the beginning.

Comment: @Dennis The pattern matches  both but will also match when there is only 1 of 2 like only `Subject:` due to the alternation `|` Op's pattern also works like this not taking the leading and trailing `/` into account and note that the @ does not have to be escaped.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was all wrong. It doesn't work. It matches either of these two, but it has to match them together. If the condition 1 AND the condition 2 are true = accept it. If either the condition 1 or the condition 2 are not true = do not accept it.